# WCF hosted in IIS - configuration trouble

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis, rest

I made a WCF REST service and Silverlight client. Communication (based on XML) on Localhost (Development server) works fine, but not on IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2). WCF service is successfully hosted on IIS, but when the client sends a request for service, the service returns Status: Aborted (wtf? - not html classic status like 404,200, but Aborted). The Silverlight client throws System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. BUT, if I send two request in quick succession, the first returns Aborted, the second WORKS! Then Silverlight falls. I do not understand it... Thank you in advance for your answer!

WCF Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>    
    <services>
      <service name="RESTapi_test.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RESTapi_test.IRestServiceImpl" 
              behaviorConfiguration="web" >

        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

   <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
     </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
     <behavior name="web">
       <webHttp/>
     </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service and inspect the trace files to know the reason why your first request fails and not the second one. Also make sure about the configuration of the service on IIS.